# ADF single-click editable pivot table

Tags: pivot-table, oracle-adf

I saw the demo of single-click editable pivot table from Oracle (link below).

http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/feature/pivotTable/pivotTableEdit.jspx

Is this from new release? which one? I'm using 11.1.1.6.0 but needs double click to activate edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this feature for the pivot table is available since ADF 12c. I'm already using it, but it seems a little bit buggy.